# mathematical proof of fast convergence of an nature-inspired algorithm

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, algorithms, artificial-intelligence, algorithmic-randomness

I am using the Moth-flame optimization algorithm to solve a problem. The algorithm uses logarithmic spiral to update the position of the moths. I have been asked to provide a mathematical proof to prove the fast convergence of the algorithm.

I have already provided the results on some benchmark functions (CEC 2005, 2009), however, I have been asked to provide detailed theoretical proofs.

If anyone is working in the area of swarm intelligence or any other bio-inspired optimization algorithms, can you please help me. TIA.

Comment: I tried to inform myself about the algorithm from https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Moth_flame_optimization Unfortunately, that article is awfully written and contains some obvious errors (e.g., in $S(M_i,F_i)=D_ie^{bt}\cos 2\pi t + F_j$ there is not only an index typo ($F_i$ or $F_j$), but $D_i$ is also weirdly defined to also depend on $j$, but most of all $D_ie^{bt}\cos 2\pi t$ is a real number and $F_j$ is a vector. Even if we turn $D_i$ into a vector, the moth would move along a line instead of a spiral.

Comment: Yes, It is confusing. But I need help in any form. Would be really grateful.

Comment: You will need some assumptions on the cost. For starters, maybe assume convexity with a global optimum, and then show that every iteration the solution must improve.  For a general cost function (with potentially infinite local optima), the best that can be shown is usually that you will at least converge to a local optimimum. So maybe show that if *at least one* is found/nearby your initial agents, then you will converge to it? Just some thoughts. Maybe consider the conditions/probability under which you will find a *better* optimum distance $d$ away, given you've found some optimum.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes, in my amateur studies I have seen many examples of poorly-described "zoological" optimization methods on second-rate journal sites (often paywalled so I frequently have only the abstracts to go by).  The mathematics is typically gibberish, the whole "scene" smacks of laziness and narcissism.  Methods and results are difficult to ascertain and interpret.  Conversely, some of them seem to work quite well, so YMMV.